# Moving App.xaml from a Windows 8 Store app project folder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-8

I am working on a Windows 8 Store app project (C#).

The application project files reside in a root folder, where each supported platform's specific files are placed inside its own folder:

```
 ROOT  
  |-- Application.Windows8.csproj  
  |-- Application.OtherPlatform.csproj
  |--
  |-- Windows8
          |-- App.xaml
          |-- Other Win8 related files
```

My Windows8 project includes all files under the Windows8 folder, including App.xaml.

When attempting to use this structure, i am getting an error when building the project:

*The Application main file must be named App.xaml*

**Is it possible to keep the App.xaml in a folder that is not the same one as the *csproj* file ?**

**UPDATE:**

I have opened a ticket on MS Connect, since the documentation never specified it is required for this file to be located in the root folder: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776168/windows-8-store-app-project-doesnt-compile-if-app-xaml-is-placed-in-a-subfolder

Comment: I noticed another thing while developing windows store app that if you try to change the entry point of a windows store app project from App.xaml to a new xaml file let's say "MainApp.xaml" in Package.appxmanifest file even then it gives the same error "The Application main file must be named App.xaml". I changed the build action attribute in properties window for "MainApp.xaml" to "ApplicationDefiition" even then it doesn't help. App.xaml is THE HARD-CODED ENTRY POINT for windows store apps which can't be changed. Though there is hardly ever a need to do so but a good to know fact.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible due to restriction on Windows Store Application.

From [MSDN -> Application class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application)

> Note  The Application main file must be named App.xaml.

There is no such restriction on normal WPF apps.

Comment: The file is named app.xaml. Where does it say it is required to reside in the project's root folder?